# Replace DataFrame graph in Kivy on button press

Tags: matplotlib, kivy

I've writing a Kivy App which will display a graph of a Pandas DataFrame via kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg, and on a button press regenerate the graph (showing different data) based on other inputs in the UI.  When I run my program it generates the first graph just fine.  But pressing the button does not change the graph, even though I've called plt.clf(), generated a new DataFrame, and called plot() on that DataFrame.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class MyApp(App):
    def plot_random_data(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
        df.plot()

    def on_plot_button_press(self, instance):
        # TODO: This does not actually refresh graph with the new random data!
        print('Plot button pressed')
        plt.clf()
        self.plot_random_data()

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # The first plot of data works ...
        self.plot_random_data()

        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        button_area = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, 0.10))
        box.add_widget(button_area)
        btn1 = Button(text='Plot')
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.on_plot_button_press)
        button_area.add_widget(btn1)

        return box

MyApp().run()
```

UPDATE: John Anderson's answer below makes the graph refresh with the new data.  However, after 20 pushes of the button, you get this error:

```
 /Users/rougex/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:320: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
   fig = self.plt.figure(figsize=self.figsize)
```

I found the way to fix this is to call plt.close(self.plot.figure), so the final working code for on_plot_button_press is:

```
    def on_plot_button_press(self, instance):
        plt.close(self.plot.figure)
        self.plot_random_data()
        self.root.remove_widget(self.plot)
        self.plot = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())
        self.root.add_widget(self.plot, index=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be any way to change the plot displayed in a `FigureCanvasKivyAgg`. So, you must replace the `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` instead. Here is a modified version of your `MyApp` that does that:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def plot_random_data(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
        df.plot()

    def on_plot_button_press(self, instance):
        # TODO: This does not actually refresh graph with the new random data!
        print('Plot button pressed')
        plt.clf()
        self.plot_random_data()
        self.root.remove_widget(self.plot)
        self.plot = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())
        self.root.add_widget(self.plot, index=1)

    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        # The first plot of data works ...
        self.plot_random_data()
        self.plot = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())
        box.add_widget(self.plot)
        button_area = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, 0.10))
        box.add_widget(button_area)
        btn1 = Button(text='Plot')
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.on_plot_button_press)
        button_area.add_widget(btn1)

        return box
```

The `build()` method save a reference to the `FigureCanvasKivyAgg`, and that is used to remove it from the `BoxLayout` in the `on_plot_button_press()` method. That method then creates a new plot (saving a reference), creates a new `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` and adds it to the `BoxLayout`. The `add_widget()` method use the `index` parameter to insert it in the correct position in the `BoxLayout`.